# Oracle sql trigger to update table based on update of another field in the same table

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I would like to create a trigger that updates a field in a table after an update of a different field in the same table. I don't think this is possible with an 'after insert or update' trigger. It compiles but when I update the field it mutates.

I have created a 'before insert or update' trigger which works for inserts, but doesn't work for updates.

This is my code:

```
create or replace
trigger TRIGGER_1
after insert or update of TOTAL_COUNT on TABLE_1
for each row
when (new.TOTAL_COUNT = 0)
begin
update TABLE_1
set count_accuracy_cde = 'absent';
end;
```

Comment: Your trigger tries to update **all** rows in `table_1`. Which row do you **really** want to change? The one that is being updated?

Comment: Yes, I just want to update the row that has been updated

Comment: The ekochegin's answer is what you are looking for. No `UPDATE` required, just assign the value.

Comment: You cannot modify `:new` for after insert Trigger.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace
trigger TRIGGER_1
before insert or update on test_table
referencing new as new old as old
for each row
begin
    if (:new.TOTAL_COUNT = 0) then
        :new.count_accuracy_cde := 'absent';
    end if;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting this error - Error: ORA-04084: cannot change NEW values for this trigger type

Comment: Try to add "referencing" clause. I've the code snipped above updated

Comment: You cannot modify `:new` for after insert Trigger.

Comment: Woohoo. Yeah, I missed that part.
Sure you need to use "before" in order to update new value

Comment: Yep. So can't be done with an after trigger. Looks like I'll need a stored procedure instead to pick up any updates to the row. Thanks all!

Comment: Why don' use "before" trigger? It can do exactly what you need

Comment: Before trigger doesn't pick up updates to the field if the row already exists. It fires for inserted rows but doesn't fire when the field is updated, which is the problem I was trying to solve.

Comment: Sorry, was absent for a while.
You are wrong it does

create table tab_test(num_col number, text_col varchar2(10));

create or replace
trigger TRIGGER_1
before insert or update on tab_test
referencing new as new old as old
for each row
begin
    dbms_output.put_line(:new.num_col);
end;

insert into eko_test values(1, '25'); -- writes 1 in output

update eko_test
   set num_col = 1000; -- writes 1000 in output